# Are Headless Services updated "atomic" in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on a Kubernetes integration of the database Apache IoTDB which supports a Cluster mode. Currently, to start a cluster each node needs to know the IP adresses of all other nodes in its "ensemble" upfront, before starting.

I think the default approach to this in Kubernetes would generally be to use a StatefulSet and a headless Service. And the startup loop I scratched would be something like this

1. start each pod with a container which contains a "pre-start" script
2. In the pre-start script wait until all other pods of the set are started and get all their ip adresses from the headless service)
3. update the configs / env variables with all cluster ip adresses
4. start the iotdb instance(s)

So the only question I have is for step 2: When do I know that all pods are started?
Is the update of the DNS / A records of the headless Service atomic in the sense that I see all pods or no pod?
OR do I have to query the API Server separately to see the number of replicas and then wait until I got all their records from the headless service?

Or is there a more kubernetes-like way to achieve that?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a DNS address of a headless service is resolved, it returns a list of Pods (ie. IPs) from an underlying endpoint object. The endpoint object always holds the list of **Ready** pods.

So, you will get the list of **Ready** pods of that moment on resolving headless service DNS.

Comment: Thank you Kamol, so I would need a ready probe to return true from the first second on, to be able to fetch their IPs. BUT I would still need to check the API to know if I got all (to avoid race conditions), right?

Comment: I think it won't work. Guessing, you are using statefulSet, the second pod won't appear until the first pod is running. The same goes for the third one, it will wait for the second one to be running, and so on.

Comment: One possible solution will be, as you mentioned, somehow pass the number of replicas to the pods, and keep discovering until the list matches the requirement.

Or, do as some other distributed system do, when a new pod join the cluster, it will communicate other ready pods, and update the list via API call.

Comment: Do you know, out of the box, if the StatefulSet waits for the pod to be ready or to be live? In case of ready this would mean that we "only" need a "always on" ready probe, right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Initially, while scheduling pods, the statefulSet controller waits for the current pod `pod.status.condition[].type=Ready` to become `true`, once it becomes true, it start scheduling the next pod.

Comment: I was referring to the question what exactly needs to happen that a pod has the status ready? Is it the success of a readinessProbe or some other condition?